# Generate AES key in C# for windows store app

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8.1

i need to genearte a 256 bit key for AES Encryption in c# fore a windows Store App. Ised the following code and is getting an execption. Please point me where I am doing wrong.

```
public string GenAESkey()
        {

            UInt32 keySize = 32;
            CryptographicKey key;
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider Algorithm = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcb);
            IBuffer keymaterial = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom((keySize + 7) / 8);
            try
            {
                key = Algorithm.CreateSymmetricKey(keymaterial);
                return key.ToString();
            }

            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
```

The error is "Value does not fall within the expected range." @ the `Algorithm.CreateSymmetricKey(keymaterial);` command.

Comment: Guess what? An AES-256 key is 256 bits. Thats 32 bytes, not 32 bits. Also, I'd be surprised if key.ToString() does anything useful.

Comment: @GregS: Thanks. That solved It.. I need to convert it to string because Iam passing it to some Functions that are already written with string argument.

Answer (score 1):

my bad. The problem was in this.

```
UInt32 keySize = 32;
```

Changed it to

```
UInt32 keySize = 256;
```

and evrything is good